# C++ Error C3867, something to do with functions within a class

Tags: c++

I get two compiler errors:
1   error C3867: 'GalaxyModel::integrand': function call missing argument list; use '&GalaxyModel::integrand' to create a pointer to member

2   IntelliSense: argument of type "double (GalaxyModel::*)(double R)" is incompatible with parameter of type "double (*)(double)"

Here is my code:

```
class GalaxyModel

{
// private variables:
double beta;
double rs, rhos, rho0, rhalf;


double integrate(double (*targetfunction)(double), double a, double b, int n)
{
// Integrator using Simpson's method
// It operates on any target function that returns type double.

if (n%2 == 1) // check that n is even.
{
    cout << "Error: must have even number of divisions\n";
    return 0;
}

int j;
double h = (b-a) / n;
double sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;

for (j=1; j<= (n/2)-1; j++)
{ sum1 = sum1 + targetfunction(a + 2*j*h); }

for (j=1; j<=n/2; j++)
{ sum2 = sum2 + targetfunction(a+ (2*j -1)*h); }

return (h/3) * (targetfunction(a) + 2*sum1 + 4*sum2 + targetfunction(b));
}


double integrand(double R)
    // This is the integrand in the assqtimesnu function    
{
    return pow(R, 2* beta) * Plummer(R) * gravprime(R); 
}


double assqtimesnu(double r)

{
return (1/pow(r, 2* beta)) * integrate(GalaxyModel::integrand, r, rhalf*50, 200);  // C3867
}


public:
GalaxyModel (double, double, double, double, double);  // constructor to initialize the     parameters
GalaxyModel (); // constructor with default parameters used
double assqfn (double r);

};


double GalaxyModel::assqfn (double r)
{
return assqtimesnu(r) / Plummer(r);
}


int main()
{


double r;
GalaxyModel gal1;  // default parameters will be used

do {
    cout << "Enter a value of r (999 to exit): ";
    cin >> r;
    if (r != 999) printf( "\nAverage sigma squared at that radius is %f\n\n",    gal1.assqfn(r) );
} while (r != 999);

}
```

If I put "static" in front of the integrand function, the error goes away but different errors appear regarding "a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object".

I am admittedly a beginner to c++ and haven't mastered pointers and references (*, & and -> confuse me sometimes). Any help or guidance is appreciated. Sorry for posting so much code but I wanted to be complete. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmmm! Your question could be improved a lot by [narrowing down](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23984942/edit) to the problematic parts of the code!

Comment: Good comment, I will edit it and trim it down.

Answer (score 2):

`integrand` is a member function. You can only have a *member function pointer* to it.

#### A possible solution:

Make integrate a function template like so:

```
template< typename Func >
double integrate( Func targetFunction, double a, double b, int n)
```

This has the additional advantage of being able to take every function object, not only function pointers!

Then instead of giving integrate a member function pointer to `integrand`, you **bind** the member function pointer to `this`:

```
// function call in the corresponding line looks like this:
integrate( std::bind(&GalaxyModel::integrand, this, std::placeholders::_1), r, rhalf*50, 200 )
```

Reference for [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) (you need to [`#include <functional>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional))

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I don't fully understand it though. If you have any suggestions for further reading on "bind" and "placeholders", please let me know, and thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The function you passed in is this one.

```
public:
double integrand(double R);
```

Since you declared it inside the class it is a member function. To call a member function you need an object pointer that will become the `this` pointer inside the function. The compiler is telling you that this (member) function is incompatible with your declaration (of a non-member function). Which of course, it is.

The best solution to this problem is the one given in the answer by @Loopunroller. For fear of subjecting you to [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) I offer this alternative simpler approach.

Simply change the declaration of this function (usually in the header file) to make it static. Now the function loses access to the `beta` member. So repeat the process, and make that static too.

```
class {
...
public:
  static double integrand(double R);
  static double beta;
...
};
double GalaxyModel::beta;
```

That should fix it. When you're happy you understand, then move over to using the template/bind solution for extra power.

---

Sorry, I misread which function on the first round. Edited to refer to the correct function.

Comment: The function causing the error is the "integrand" function. If I make it static, the original error goes away but new ones appear, regarding "a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object". This applies to the variable "beta" for example. I do appreciate your help though.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, changed to refer to the right function. You need to make `beta` static too.